# How to start Sublime Text 3 with a new file open along with the files opened in the last session

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext

Instead of pressing `Ctr + N` for a new file, is there a way to automate that process whenever we start Sublime Text 3, along with the old files loaded as usual.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the `subl` executable supports an argument `--command`.

Therefore, you need to launch `subl` using `subl --command new_file` to get it to open a new blank tab along with the previously opened files.

Depending how you normally launch Sublime Text, you may want to edit a launcher icon/shortcut to include this argument.

Comment: This worked when i started SL3 using subl.exe. Thanks a lot. However, the default shortcut SL3 created was executing sublime_text.exe instead of subl.exe. When I use the same with sublime_text.exe it opened two files. Strange!!! Do you know the reason?

Comment: Interesting - I can confirm the same, but only when ST3 is not already running. I don't know the reason why, but I would guess it has to do with that it sometimes tries to open a blank tab by default, and using the `new_file` command therefore makes it open two...

Comment: Yeah, quite possible. Thanks a lot buddy.